# Can you auto fill out a form using CURL

Tags: flash, curl

So I am new to CURL and understand that you can auto fill out the form. However, I don't and will not know the GET or POST url. Basically I have to enter some info then upload a file but it has to be automated and was told that CURL can emulate what I do manually. Is this true and or possible?

EDIT*********

Forgot to mention the form is a flash file. Ugghh, this seems almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

cURL probably could do that, but not knowing the URL is a big problem.  You could look into some other solution like [WWW::Mecahnize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/), [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) possibly. See here [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967721/how-to-programmatically-fill-out-flash-forms) for more ideas.

Comment: Is it possible to get the input id's of the form elements on a flash form?